# Displaying unknown coordiates and present location on same map

Tags: html, geolocation

I am trying to display latitude and longitude coordinates on a map. This works fine but once this is displayed I also want to display the users current location on the same map while displaying the other position as well. Could someone please tell me how that is done. This is what I use to display the Lat and Longitude.

```
function showPosition()
{
//var latlon=position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;
var lat = document.getElementById("saved_lat").value;
var lon = document.getElementById("saved_lon").value;

var img_url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
 + lat + "," + lon +"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML="<img src='"+img_url+"'>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to get the user's current lat/lng position. Then you will need to use the 'markers' parameter in the static map to show two markers, one for the saved position and one for the user's position.

You can get a description on how to use markers here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1#MarkerLocations

Below is a working modification of your code. Here's some tips:

1. I hardwired the saved_lat/lon values in the  statements for demo'ing purposes. You will need to replace these or use your own HTML code.
2. The user's coordinate are obtained form the HTML geolocation method navigator.geolocation. This method will pass the lat/lon of the user's location to the ShowPosition() function.
3. I updated your ShowPosition() function:

   A. Take the user's lat/lon as parameters
   B. Added variable 'markers' to set two markers (saved and user's) in the google static map.
   C. Added variable 'zoom' to set the zoom level.

```
<script>
    // Get User's Coordinate from their Browser
    window.onload = function () {
        // HTML5/W3C Geolocation
        if ( navigator.geolocation )
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( UserLocation );
        // Default to Washington, DC
        else
            ShowPosition( 38.8951, -77.0367 );
    }

    // Callback function for asynchronous call to HTML5 geolocation
    function UserLocation( position )
    {
        ShowPosition( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude );
    }

    function ShowPosition( user_lat, user_lon )
    {   
        var lat = document.getElementById("saved_lat").value; 
        var lon = document.getElementById("saved_lon").value;

        var markers = "&markers=color:blue|label:S|" + lat + "," + lon + "|" + user_lat + "," + user_lon;
        var zoom="&zoom=11";

        var img_url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
        + lat + "," + lon +"&size=400x300&sensor=false" + zoom + markers;
    document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML="<img src='"+img_url+"'>";
}
</script>


<body>
    <div id="mapholder"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="saved_lat" value="45.65"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="saved_lon" value="-122.45"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried this but the map does not open :/

Comment: I just tried my code. It works in FF and IE10. For some reason it is not working in my Chrome browser.